# Glossary: Choose the place where to put the glossary within the table of contents

Tags: glossaries

I want to put my glossary at the end of my document. I succeeded to do that. But the problem is within the table of contents (TOC): It shows the glossary twice (at the beginning and at the end).

It appears at:

1. the begining because of  "\loadglsentries" (I am using an external file): 
   [image: code_part1]
2. the end where I placed "\printglossary" while using the option "toc" with the "glossaries" package:
   [image: code_part2]

My question is: how could I just show the glossary at the end of TOC, in its right place?

Thank you and sorry (it is my first post!)

[image: Table of contents_1]
[image: Table of contents_2]

Comment: That's not normal behaviour. Perhaps you have `\addcontentsline` line somewhere in your document that's confusing things. (You also have two bibliography entries for page 45, so there seems to be some duplication in your document.)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot , yes, I had two entries for the bibliography because I used \addcontentsline and added the "tocbibind" package. I solved it by adding the option 'notbib" like this: \usepackage[nottoc,notbib,notindex]{tocbibind}. For the glossary, I checked the whole code (main.tex) but there is no \addcontentsline for it. Finally I checked my glossary.tex and surprise! There is an \addcontentsline for the glossary! I spend hours on this problem. Really, thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the presence of another \addcontentsline for the glossary in the glossary.tex file in addition of the one I'd put in the main.tex.